# How can one build a MSI from Raspberry Pi or Gitlab CI from a Java Project

Tags: java, docker, raspberry-pi, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm trying to make an installer for a JavaFX-Application which has a dedicated CI/CD via GitLab. The last step would be to create an installer for Windows on a Raspberry Pi (an ARM-based system). Since the official javapackager can only build files for Windows on Windows I would love to read some suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need an installer, can't it be just a portable version, for example [executable JAR](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) file?

Comment: You might be interested in the new [Packaging Tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343), but it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: *"The last step would be to create an installer for Windows on a Raspberry Pi (an ARM-based system)"* - I don't really see that happening until the tool that Boris linked to becomes available (which looks great). You need a Windows runner for the time being, Windows and RPI do not love each other yet. Probably the most minimal system you could get away with is a compute stick or something similar.

Comment: Thank you @Borris (and also @Gimby) for the quick answers. The reason I need to create a platform-specific installer is that requiring Java to run an application, which should be easy to install, is just not user-friendly at all - especially if you consider that the application should also be used by IT-newbies.